# LINQ equivalent of a join query;

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Normally in t-sql if i use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

it returns all columns of all tables,how can i achieve that in linq?

Tried:

```
var query = from siparis in db.Siparis
            join kazan in db.Kazan on siparis.ID equals kazan.Siparis_ID into Joined
            select Joined;
```

But it only returns me objects,not everything.

Comment: This can only be done when you know all the properties of the both elements in both collections. Then you can use `Select` to project a new anonymous type value having all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return both objects, or a selection from each. This is specified in a comment in your question. But I just thought an example would help.

```
var query = from siparis in db.Siparis
            join kazan in db.Kazan on siparis.ID equals kazan.Siparis_ID 
            select new { 
                         siparis, 
                         kazan
                       };
```

or

```
var query = from siparis in db.Siparis
            join kazan in db.Kazan on siparis.ID equals kazan.Siparis_ID 
            select new { 
                         SiparisID = siparis.ID, 
                         KazanID = kazan.ID,
                         SiparisColumnX = sipariz.X,
                         KazanColumnX = kazan.X
                       };
```

Comment: I see,but I also must know all the properties of each object right?So there isn't  a "*" equivalent.

Comment: You do need to know which columns to project to the new anonymous object shown in example 2 above. I usually use the approach in the first example when I would want to have access to all fields.

Answer (score 0):

this is the equivalent

```
var query = from siparis in db.Siparis
               join kazan in db.Kazan on siparis.ID equals kazan.Siparis_ID
               select siparis;
```

For getting the results add .ToList at the end like

```
var query = (from siparis in db.Siparis
               join kazan in db.Kazan on siparis.ID equals kazan.Siparis_ID
               select siparis).ToList();
```